# How to read a bash variable value set by xargs?

Tags: bash

How do we read a bash variable value set by xargs from its subshell run ?
eg:

```
export VID
echo 1 | xargs -I% sh -c "echo % | echo ID=% && VID=%"
echo $VID
```

We are expecting VID to print 1
but $VID returns blank

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly; you want to pass the echoed value to ID and VID in the subshell with xargs. As VID has been exported previously without a value, the new value should be passed from the subshell to the parent shell; i.e. commanding `echo $VID` is expected to produce the value it received in the subshell.

If the values in the subshell actually got set, I should be able to echo these values within the subshell with `echo $ID` and `echo $VID`, but

```
pg@TREX:~$ echo 42 | xargs -I% sh -c "echo % | ID=% && VID=%; echo $ID; echo $VID"

55
pg@TREX:~$
```

I exported VID with value 55 in the beginning just for clarity. Clearly neither ID nor VID did receive values in the subshell. After playing around a bit I came up with:

```
pg@TREX:~$ echo 42 | xargs -I % sh -c 'ID=%; VID=%; echo $ID; echo $VID'
42
42
pg@TREX:~$
```

However afterwards

```
pg@TREX:~$ echo $VID
55
pg@TREX:~$
```

Adding `export VID=%` as last part of the xargs command didn't change the result. But at least the variables actually did get values within the subshell.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Peregrino69 - thx for responding. Not exactly what we are looking for .

Comment: You's welcome. Did I misunderstand the purpose? I generally drop scripting questions to either https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/